# How to enable SCSS inline template for angular component style with angular cli

Tags: sass, angular-cli, angular

At [Codelyzer test file](https://github.com/comfroels/codelyzer/blob/0573e934e24feb57c09b40b7185042e65b21f832/test/noUnusedCssRule.spec.ts#L789...L797) I saw SCSS beeing used in a styles inline template. Is it possible to enable it with Angular CLI?

My SCSS setup is working when using `styleUrls` but not for direct `styles` component decorator property.

*Update:*

I am using Angular CLI 1.0.0 with Angular 4.0.1

This is the error in shown in the WebStorm IDE

[image: error in the WebStorm IDE]

Comment: I imagine it would be available with a Webpack plugin -- if not now sometime in the future. That said, I don't think it is available in angular-cli at the moment.

Comment: would be nice to know the name of the plugin if there is a webpack plugin

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Support for inline SCSS in `@Component` decorator `styles` field is available from Angular v12

To enable in existing applications add `"inlineStyleLanguage": "scss"` to `angular.json` in the following sections

- architect.build.options
- architect.test.options

For a new Angular CLI project where `scss` is the selected style the `inlineStyleLanguage` configuration will default to `scss`

Comment: can you use it in the template tho ?

cause it looks like to me that it's only in the component definition  `Starting in v12, Angular components will now support inline Sass in the styles field of the @Component decorator`

Comment: The closing quotation on the `scss` needs to be corrected to save someone some debugging time.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, (at this moment) it is not possible. From the Angular documentation:

> Style strings added to the @Component.styles array *must be written in CSS* because the CLI cannot apply a preprocessor to inline styles.

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#non-css-style-files

Comment: So I guess if I want to target the host element I have to use a separate file?

Comment: No, `:host{ ... }` styles still work with component inline styles.

Comment: This answer is no longer true