# Angular - Can't access Material theming functions after upgrade to v12

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I just upgraded Angular project to latest version (medium size project with Angular Material).
When trying to build it I get following errors from multiple components' `scss` files.

```
./src/app/layout/navbar/navbar.component.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined function.
  ╷
7 │     color: mt.get-color-from-palette(theme.$foreground, inverted);
  │            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\app\layout\navbar\navbar.component.scss 7:12  root stylesheet
```

Weird thing is that when inspecting imports in file in question I get following:

```
// navbar.component.scss
@use '~@angular/material' as mat; // Ctrl + click -> path inaccessible
@use '../../../theme/goscan-theme' as theme; // Ctrl + click -> opens the file
@use '~@angular/material/theming' as mt; // Ctrl + click -> opens the file
```

Installed dependencies:

```
"@angular/animations": "~12.0.2",
"@angular/cdk": "~12.0.2",
"@angular/common": "~12.0.2",
"@angular/compiler": "~12.0.2",
"@angular/core": "~12.0.2",
"@angular/forms": "~12.0.2",
"@angular/localize": "^12.0.2",
"@angular/material": "^12.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.2",
"@angular/router": "~12.0.2",
...
```

I already followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67732178/3359635) to fix some build errors but I can't get pass this one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#reading-hues-from-palettes

In your case, you need to use `mat.get-color-from-palette` (instead of `mt.get-color-from-palette`), as the `get-color-from-palette` function lives in `'~@angular/material'` package.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, together with `mat.line-height`, `mat.font-family` and `mat.font-size`