# Angular 6 to 12 Migration: Getting Multiple Warning: Css Minimizer Plugin: > Unexpected "$"

Tags: angular, angular12

After migrating my angular 6 project to 12.
I am getting multiple warning in terminal

if in angular.json i set optimisation: false configuration then all issue get resolved but i don't want to make this changes it should be true only.

with optimisation: true i am getting all these warnings:-

Earlier same code was working fine without any warning.

```
assets/.../variables.scss - Warning: Css Minimizer Plugin:  > assets/.../variables.scss:6:0: warning: Unexpected "$"
    6 │ $color-normal-gray:#8a8a8a;
      ╵ ^

assets/.../global.scss - Warning: Css Minimizer Plugin:  > 
assets/.../global.scss:285:2: warning: Expected identifier but found "."
    285 │   .dropdown-menu{
        ╵   ^

assets/.../global.scss - Warning: Css Minimizer Plugin:  > 
assets/.../global.scss:255:6: warning: Expected identifier but found "*"
    255 │       *background-color: #d9d9d9;
        ╵       ^

assets/.../master.scss - Warning: Css Minimizer Plugin:  > 
assets/.../master.scss:567:8: warning: Expected ":" but found "{"
    567 │   circle {
        ╵          ^
```

My Package.json is below:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.1.0",
    "@okta/okta-angular": "^3.0.1",
    "@okta/okta-auth-js": "^4.7.1",
    "angular-datatables": "^0.6.4",
    "angular-image-slider": "0.0.8",
    "autobind-decorator": "^2.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.3.0",
    "json-bigint": "^1.0.0",
    "jsrsasign": "^10.3.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.10",
    "ng-simple-slideshow": "^1.2.4",
    "ng2-scroll-to-el": "^1.2.1",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.4.7",
    "ngx-filter-pipe": "^2.1.2",
    "ngx-logger": "3.3.11",
    "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.0",
    "pagination": "file:src/app/packages/pagination-0.0.1.tgz",
    "rxjs": "7.3.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.2",
    "sass": "^1.36.0",
    "single-spa": "^5.9.2",
    "single-spa-angular": "^5.0.2",
    "systemjs": "^6.8.3",
    "true-case-path": "^1.0.3",
    "tslint": "^6.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.110",
    "@types/node": "14.6.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.2",
    "await": "^0.2.6",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fs-promise": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-inline-css": "^3.3.0",
    "gulp-inline-source": "^4.0.0",
    "htmlhint-ng2": "0.0.13",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "mediaquery-text": "1.0.7",
    "ng-bullet": "^1.0.3",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "puppeteer": "^1.14.0",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "tslint-sonarts": "^1.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
```

Comment: You use a custom-webpack from angular. That's where it comes from. What is the webpack configuration associated to your css loader ?

Comment: this is micro app and i am using standard webpack configuration of single-spa-angular which is  as per (singleSpaAngularWebpack = require("single-spa-angular/lib/webpack"))

Comment: I don't have any custom webpack. I am also seeing this.

Comment: Did you skip versions in between?

Comment: Do you have a sample project we can reproduce this on? If we cannot reproduce it, we cannot really come up with a fix.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was having the same issue, I found out that in my case the assets config on `angular.json` was the one to blame. Check this piece of code from the configuration:

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "ngx-build-plus:build",
      "options": {
        "aot": true,
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "assets": [
          "src/assets",
          "src/favicon.ico"
        ]
}
}
```

Inside the `src/assets` folder there was a bunch of stylesheet code, `scss`, `less`, `css` and it seems that the CSS Minifier just tries to handle everything there as plain CSS.
The solution is to remove from this assets any non-processed stylesheets and just leave them under `styles` config on the `angular.json`. That did the trick for me, hope it helps you too!

Answer (score 25):

Your problem is related to processing of the scss file. This problem is detailed in the [67607413](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67607413/you-tried-to-parse-scss-with-the-standard-css-parser-try-again-with-the-postcss). In shortly, If scss files are removed or omitted from assets folder, this problem will be solved. I preferred omitting SCSS files.

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "src/assets/",
        "ignore": ["**/*.scss"],
        "output": "/assets/"
    },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. You should change the import of 'assets/.../variables.scss' to './assets/.../variables.scss'. In my case it was in styles.scss but it can be in every .scss file.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the problem comes from the *configuration files* related to `single-spa-angular` architecture, Although the error simply says that:

> I'm trying to minify Sass css files in your project but the syntax is
> unknown! Perhaps I don't know anything about the syntax of Sass files!

As we can't reproduce the problem and this is a hard job to find the origin(s) of warning in SPA platforms with several configuration files but, there's a **straight way** to find the issue or reproduce the project on your own machine immediately that is comparing with or forking the [single-spa-angular repository](https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa-angular) which is made for Angular 12. Migration from Angular 6 to 12 has some pitfalls itself however you are also trying to keep such library with hidden behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling Ivy engine in `tsconfig.json` file:

> In case if you are using some outdated package which is not compatible with Ivy.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {"enableIvy": false}
```

Or, let's it give a try by running the following commands one by one:

> In case if you are upgrading Angular 6 to Angular 12 directly then there might be some issues.

```
ng update @angular/core@7 @angular/cli@7 --force
ng update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8 --force
ng update @angular/core@9 @angular/cli@9 --force
ng update @angular/core@10 @angular/cli@10 --force
ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11 --force
ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12 --force
```

Or, run just the following command:

```
ng update @angular/core --force
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have not tried disabling Ivy yet as this seems more like a hack than a solution. I tried your suggestion to force the update. However, this did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated ...the plugin expects CSS and not SCSS as input:
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/

The `angular.json` would have been rather relevant ...

Answer (score 2):

In my `package.json` **`node-sass`** was missing.

So after installing latest version of node-sass

my all CSS related error got resolved pls try and keep us posted hear.

this solution should work!

```
npm install node-sass@latest
```

Comment: That's why I have uninstalled it and install sass but after that, I start getting an error... but if you check node-sass package page in NPM, they have release  the latest version 3 months ago only.
So mean time you can keep both. i think that SASS version still need more update

Comment: or if you don't want to go with node-sass for a time being. you can keep updating your sass package. As SASS development team releasing new version very frequently you can check hear as well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass
https://github.com/sass/dart-sass

Comment: This is not solve my problem. And this library will be deprecated at future release of angular. Cons of node-sass library was explained in detail at this topic. --> .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594119/node-sass-usage-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-major-version

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue. Looks like there was some changes in **ng serve**. Now the production build is the default configuration.

You have to add the **development** options on *build* and *serve* node in `angular.json`

```
// >> projects[YOUR_PROJECT_NAME].architect.build.configurations
"configurations": {
  "development": {
    "buildOptimizer": false,
    "optimization": false,
    "vendorChunk": true,
    "extractLicenses": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "namedChunks": true
  },
// >> projects[YOUR_PROJECT_NAME].architect.serve
"serve": {
  "defaultConfiguration": "development",
  "configurations": {
    "development": {
      "browserTarget": "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME:build:development"
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

For migration from Angular 11 to 12 solution was;

Add **ignore** to `angular.json` file and remove `src/assets`

```
"assets": [
    "src/assets", <-------------------- remove
    "src/favicon.ico",
    { <------------------------------
        "glob": "**/*",             -
        "input": "src/assets/",     -
        "ignore": ["**/*.scss"],    ---- add 
        "output": "/assets/"        -
    }, <-----------------------------
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was two(!) CssMinimizerPlugins inside singleSpaWebpackConfig.optimization.minimizer/ one aiming only css and one aiming css|scss|sass|less|styl

ive checked angular 11 webpack config and it has no CssMinimizerPlugins for css|scss|sass|less|styl

also ive checked singleSpaAngularWebpack helper. and it does not add this plugin

my workarount for excluding CssMinimizerPlugins for css|scss|sass|less|styl:

```
singleSpaWebpackConfig.optimization.minimizer = singleSpaWebpackConfig.optimization.minimizer
.filter(plugin => plugin.constructor.name !== 'CssMinimizerPlugin' || plugin.options?.test?.toString().indexOf('less') === -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although correct answer is provided by @Locus B. but for those who didn't get that, here is a bit more details is added.
In my `assets` folder, there were 4 subfolders, namely `css`, `sounds`, `icons` and `images`. Providing path "src/assets" in `assets` causes above mentioned warnings. Modifying `angular.json` file will help

```js
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "ngx-build-plus:build",
      "options": {
        "aot": true,
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "assets": [
          "src/assets/images",
          "src/assets/icons",
          "src/assets/sounds",
          "src/favicon.ico"
        ]
}
}
```

Instead of `src/assets`, We provided path to images, sounds and icons. Leaving behind `css` folder.
Might be helpful for someone. Thanks